# Why does the package matter for Spring RESTful controller classes

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have the Spring sample RESTful server running. If I add controller classes to the com.example.restservice package, they work. But if I put the same class in the package net.windward.RESTfulEngine.Controllers - they are not found.

I don't see any setting anywhere. What is limiting where these controllers need to be located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring starts scanning the packages from the main package that your `@SpringBootApplication` class exists and all of its sub-packages.for your case you need to use [@ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) in order to scan external packages.

Comment: That was it - thank you. Is there any documentation that covers settings like this so I don't need to ask questions? TIA

Comment: Something like this ?
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

Answer (score 1):

It could work if you would define both package patterns to scan for an example

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example, net.windward" />
```

Or in Java code would be like

```
@ComponentScan({"com.example","net.windward"})
```

But if you would want to have only one package pattern scanned, then you need to keep them in order for an example to start everything with com. and add rest of your packages.
What component scan does it starts from "com." or whatever you defined in your configuration and it goes into all subdirectories, but only subdirectories, it does not scan around it. So if you would like to scan com. and net. you need to define both of them so spring can go into both of their subdirectories.
But approaches would do the work.